# How to define a self-join through a cross-reference table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a tinder-like app in Rails (my first Rails project!), and am having some trouble getting a self join to work.

I have a user table and a swipes table.

The swipes table is:

```
t.integer  "sourceuser_id"
t.integer  "targetuser_id"
t.boolean  "liked"
```

And the user table has a user_id field (among other irrelevant columns).

Each user in the user table can be the sourceuser for many records, and also the targetuser for many records.

I am able to get the User info for the sourceuser record with the below definition.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# These work (I think)
has_many :sourceuser, :class_name => "Swipe", :foreign_key => "sourceuser_id"     
has_many :received_swipes, :class_name => "Swipe", :foreign_key => "targetuser_id"
```

However, I am unable to figure out a way to get the target user information.  That is, I want to get all the targetusers a given sourceuser has swiped.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help you can provide a very stuck rails newbie...

EDIT:

My Swipe Class:

My Swipe class:

```
class Swipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sourceuser, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :targetuser, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Comment: Is it giving an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Hey Tom, I've tried a bunch of things more complex than the above, but what I'm trying to do is generate SQL that would have 2 inner joins, a join from user(1) to swipes.sourceuser_id and then a join from swipes.targetuser_id back to user(2).  I then want to select * from user(2).


All I have been able to generate thus far is a single join: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "swipes" ON "users"."id" = "swipes"."sourceuser_id" WHERE "swipes"."targetuser_id" = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sth like:

```
has_many :source_swipes, class_name: 'Swipe', foreign_key: :sourceuser_id
has_many :received_swipes, class_name: 'Swipe', foreign_key: :targetuser_id

has_many :source_users, through: :source_swipes, source: :sourceuser
has_many :target_users, through: :received_swipes, source: :targetuser
```

Assuming your`Swipe` class belongs_to `sourceuser` and `targetuser`

Comment: Thanks, but I added your code, but the SQL generated still only has one join, not the 2nd back to the user table.  

SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "swipes" ON "users"."id" = "swipes"."targetuser_id" WHERE "swipes"."targetuser_id" = $1

Comment: It doesn't need second join for a single user. If you want to see double join do `User.joins(:target_users)`

Comment: Thanks!  My final code is:

  `has_many :source_swipes, class_name: 'Swipe', foreign_key: :sourceuser_id
  has_many :received_swipes, class_name: 'Swipe', foreign_key: :targetuser_id


  has_many :rated_users, through: :source_swipes, source: :targetuser`

And my query is: User.joins(:rated_users).select("rated_users_users.*")